# Using kubectl to rollout openshift DeploymentConfig

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-helm

I'm using `openshift` container cluster to run my project.
In my CI I'm using `helm` and `kubectl` to upgrade and rollout the deployments.

Following [this](https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-helm-openshift/) guide, I have created this simple `DeploymentConfig`:

```
apiVersion: apps.openshift.io/v1
kind: DeploymentConfig
...
```

When I run `helm upgrade --install` I can see the new deployment in my openshift cluster.
But I want to rollout the deployment using `kubectl` and it fails:

```
helm upgrade --install --wait --namespace myapp nginx chart/
kubectl rollout status -n myapp -w "dc/nginx"
```

I'm getting this error `error: no king "DeploymentConfig" is registered for version "apps.openshift.io/v1" in scheme "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubectl/scheme/scheme.go:28"`

Running `kubectl api-versions` does display "apps.openshift.io/v1" though.

Why can't I rollout the deployment using `kubectl`?

Comment: Hi,  Deployment and DeploymentConfig (OpenShift specific ) are two different resources,Kubectl client is not aware of dc

Comment: If you want to use deployment then you just need to switch to deploy `kubectl rollout status -n myapp -w "deployment/nginx"`

Comment: or if you have deployed using helm then you can use oc client `oc rollout status -n myapp -w "dc/nginx”`

Comment: Why don't you use "helm rollback <release-name>" ?

Comment: @cecunami btw, `helm rollback` doesn't suppose as the same as `kubectl/oc rollout`.

Comment: You can try modifying an annotation in the pod template. That will trigger a new deployment. See https://cookbook.openshift.org/application-lifecycle-management/how-can-i-trigger-a-new-deployment-of-an-application.html and use `kubectl` instead of `oc` when doing the patch. Also works for `Deployment`.

Comment: I'm running the pipeline in `helm-kubectl` image, that includes helm and kubectl, but not `oc`, then I hoped to manage it with `kubectl`. Introducing `oc` will be much more difficult, as I can't just split it to different stages (using gitlab ci)

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes' command line interface (CLI), **kubectl**, is used to run commands against Kubernetes cluster, while `DeploymentConfigs`is specific to OpenShift distributions, and not available in standard Kubernetes.

Though, as long as **oc** is built on top of **kubectl**, converting a **kubectl** binary to **oc** is as simple as changing the binary’s name from **kubectl** to **oc**.

See more information for [using kubectl and oc](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.10/cli_reference/differences_oc_kubectl.html#differences-oc-kubectl-using-kubectl)